# Validate Multiple email address columns and concate both columns value into 1 column value delimited by pipe using pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two email address in pyspark dataframe and need to validate both the email address columns value and then merge into 1 column value using pipe as delimiter.

```
Primary_Email_Address       Alternate_Email_Address      Output(email_address)
navg@gmail.com                nvgng@gm@.com              navg@gmail.com
ggg@gmail.com                 nnnn@gmail.com             ggg@gmail.com|nnnn@gmail.com
nave@gmail.com|gg@gmail.com   ndg@gmail.com          nave@gmail.com|gg@gmail.com|ndg@gmail.com
```

I need to pass columns dynamically  from spark dataframe csv file and handle it.

**I have written below code but need some modification.**

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit, col, trim, when
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
regex = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("file_name.csv")

# select specific columns

df1 = df.select("primary_email_addr","alt_email_addr")

# concat the columns

df_email = df1.withColumn('email_addr',concat(df1['primary_email_addr'],lit("|"),df1['alt_email_addr'])))

df_email_1 = df_email.drop("primary_email_addr","alt_email_addr")

df_email_2 = df_email_1.withColumn("email_addr_status",when(F.col("email_addr").rlike("^(([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+)+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]+)(| ([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+)+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]+)*$"),"Valid").otherwise("Invalid"))

df_email_2.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here another approach using [regexp_extract_all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all) and [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) with Spark >= 3.1.0:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

cols = ['Primary_Email_Address', 'Alternate_Email_Address']
data = [("navg@gmail.com", "nvgng@gm@.com"),
        ("ggg@gmail.com", "nnnn@gmail.com")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

concat_expr = expr("concat_ws(',', Primary_Email_Address, Alternate_Email_Address)") 
extract_expr = expr("regexp_extract_all(concat, '(\\\w+([\\\.-]?\\\w+)*@\\\w+([\\\.-]?\\\w+)*(\\\.\\\w{2,3})+)', 0)")
join_expr = expr("array_join(extract, '|')")

df.withColumn("concat", concat_expr) \
  .withColumn("extract", extract_expr) \
  .withColumn("output", join_expr) \
  .select("Primary_Email_Address", "Alternate_Email_Address", "output") 

# +---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
# |Primary_Email_Address|Alternate_Email_Address|output                      |
# +---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
# |navg@gmail.com       |nvgng@gm@.com          |navg@gmail.com              |
# |ggg@gmail.com        |nnnn@gmail.com         |ggg@gmail.com|nnnn@gmail.com|
# +---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
```

Logic:

1. Use `concat_ws` to concatanate emails.
2. Call `regexp_extract_all` to extract the array of valid emails.
3. Call `array_join` to produce s string from the previous array with items seperated by `|`.

Comment: how to select few columns from dataframe to list and iterate over each columns and apply the regex on that column ?

Comment: why you need to iterate over columns? Is your problem solved by applying the above logic or you need a different output?

Comment: Above answer is perfect. I have other problem which asked you in comment

Comment: to iterate over cols and use regexp_extract you could do something like this `[regexp_extract(c, reg_exp) for c in df.columns]` but this doesn't really make sense. I would again suggest to concatenate these columns first and then apply `regexp_extract_all` as shown above

Comment: We i have more than 1 email delimited by | in Primary_Email_Address then(agv@gmail.com| bcd@gmail.com). We need to check both the email in one column then jump to other column.

Comment: Modified my question and dataframe data please have a look in more details

Comment: code not working if we have special character like ($,%,* etc) in email address.

Comment: It is not filtering the email address which has underscore(_) after @ symbol

Comment: hi @Naveen the validity of the regex itself was not initially part of this question and it constitutes a different question.

Comment: Hi, @abiratsis, Thanks for your efforts. It resolved my issue and Yes you are right, many validation was not part of the question and asked latter. I was getting use cases in day by day so thought to discuss with you.
I resolved the underscore issue now.

Comment: I need one more help from you here. how to store invalid email id's into list and finally write to csv file. It will be great help to me.

Comment: here is the logic if one of the `Primary_Email_Address ` and `Alternate_Email_Address` does not appear in  `output`  then it means there was some invalid email :) also you could use something like col("output").contains($"Alternate_Email_Address") for the condition. The exact code is a task for you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you looking for below solution or not -

1. compare both the column
2. If there is a mismatch - identify it
3. Based on the identification, merge again

## Modified my answer - Used **`from validate_email import validate_email`** module to validate the email

**DF**

```
    from validate_email import validate_email

df = spark.createDataFrame([("navg@gmail.com","nvgng@gm@.com "),("ggg@gmail.com","nnnn@gmail.com")],["Primary_Email_Address","Alternate_Email_Address"])

valid_email_udf = udf(lambda e: validate_email(e), T.BooleanType())
df = df.withColumn('is_valid_primary', valid_email_udf('Primary_Email_Address'))
df = df.withColumn('is_valid_alternate', valid_email_udf('Alternate_Email_Address'))
df.show()
```

**Condition and final output**

```
df = df.withColumn("cond_col", F.when(F.col("is_valid_primary") == F.col("is_valid_alternate"), True).otherwise(False))
df = df.withColumn("merged_email", F.when(F.col("cond_col") == True, F.concat_ws("|","Primary_Email_Address", "Alternate_Email_Address" )).otherwise(None))
df.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+
|Primary_Email_Address|Alternate_Email_Address|is_valid_primary|is_valid_alternate|cond_col|merged_email                |
+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+
|navg@gmail.com       |nvgng@gm@.com          |true            |false             |false   |null                        |
|ggg@gmail.com        |nnnn@gmail.com         |true            |true              |true    |ggg@gmail.com|nnnn@gmail.com|
+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we no need to compare this two columns. I need to validate this 2 email address columns and then concate the final value into 1 value by pipe delimiter.

Comment: what do you mean by validation ? string before the domain of both the email address are same or not , needs to be checked ? is it ? i.e. abc@gmail.com and pqr@gmail.com , so you want to check that abc and pqr are same or not ? is that a correct understanding ? pls confirm

Comment: No we are not comparing the two columns. We need to email validation for both the columns. Particular email is valid or not.

Comment: okay- I have updated the code logic - pls check and let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks for the code but in 'merged_email' column instead of null i need valid email address like 'navg@gmail.com'  as output.. drop the invalid email address

Comment: I have kept null as I was not sure on the logic - you can use any column in the otherwise condition as per the requirembt